# Check if all values in array are false

Tags: javascript

I have an array of values and want to check if all of them evaluate to `false`.

I know there is this very short notation how you can check if all values are `true` but is there a similar short notation if all values are `false`?

```js
const values = [true, false, false]

values.every(Boolean)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, there is no "simpler" way than the following:

```js
const values = [true, false, false]

const result = values.every(value => !value)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: When the array contains `undefined` value, it returns true. that's not the correct answer.

Comment: It also means the precondition of the OP is false. If there's `1`, `"abc"`, etc, his function evaluates to true.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) as a different approach. Checking if some of the elements are `true` then negate it.

Like the following:

```js
const values = [true, false, false];
const result = !values.some(e => e);
console.log(result);
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const values = [undefined, false, false]

const func1 = (array)=> array.every(value => !value);
const func2 = (array)=> array.every(value => value!==undefined && !value);

console.log(func1(values)) // true
console.log(func2(values)) // false => This is a better way
```

Try like this:
First, we check that element not undefined, and then it equals to `false`.